# :Visited Links Without Leaving page

Tags: javascript, css, anchor

I am building a Sharepoint page currently.  The page uses anchor tags for links that instead of navigating away from the page, fire a modal dialog box.  These are to function as if they are normal links. **NOTE:** the div contents are pulled in via rest meaning they are populated through javascript functions, so editing the css manually will not persist.

I am using the anchor tags because I want access to the :visited tag so users know which links they have viewed before.  The issue here is that I had been using placeholder tags of **href='#'**.  This does not give me the intended results, because when each link has **href='#'**, visiting one link changes the color of all links on the page.

I attempted to include the link being opened through my Dialog box function so that each link would have a unique URL, but in order to avoid navigating away from the page, my function returns false, which in turn does not trigger the **:visited** event.

Is there any way for me to have unique URLs that will differentiate **non-static** Div entries with **:visited** subclasses without having the anchor navigate away from the current page?

```
<a class="hyper" href="myLinkHere" onclick="return myDialog(//start dialog then return false);">This is a Title</a>
```

Comment: User click link, add class to the link. Define a css rule for the class you added, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to preserve the link state *in one session*, then just manage it in javascript. Before you return false, alter the CSS class or do whatever else you'd planned to alter the appearance of the link.

If your intention is to preserve the link state *across sessions*, then use a combination of javascript on the client side and whatever you're using on the server side to maintain that state for a given user.

I know in some sense it would be easier to keep it all client side if you could, but let's face it--the user isn't actually *visiting* anything when they click on the link, and so it is not necessarily the most logical choice to try to act as though they are.

Answer (score 1):

@James Waddington: Your answer is superb !! You solved this issue with a small tweak. Now i can use visited links for modal box or color box too.

You can use #something in the href to specify an internal page id to link to. If you specify an id that's not on the page, you will have a unique ID that marks the link as visited, without actually taking you anywhere. e.g..

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<a href="#test2">Test</a>
<a href="#test3">Test</a>
<a href="#test4">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use #something in the href to specify an internal page id to link to. If you specify an id that's not on the page, you will have a unique ID that marks the link as visited, without actually taking you anywhere. e.g..

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<a href="#test2">Test</a>
<a href="#test3">Test</a>
<a href="#test4">Test</a>
```

[Quick Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9019bojn/).

Comment: If the OP returns false, visited will still not take effect (see his post). If the OP does not return false, then the url in the navbar will have these tacked onto the end, and the history will be littered with page anchors on the current page. I don't think this is a particularly good solution to the problem, because it just plays into the OP's mistaken assumption that using the visited state is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: While I think there's a very good chance you're right, and you give very sound alternatives, you are making some assumptions. As the question was actually quite specific about :visited, I thought it appropriate to give a direct answer.

Comment: He said "I am using the anchor tags because I want access to the :visited tag so users know which links they have viewed before." He's presenting two questions: "how do I make :visited work without leaving the page?", and, here, "how do I make it so that users know which links they have viewed before?" The first question is not a question about his core problem. His core problem is the one in question 2. Question 1 is about his predetermined solution to question 2. I'm saying that the predetermined solution is a poor one, and that it is more helpful to cleanly solve his actual core problem.

Comment: None of that, by the way, is challenging your right to give a direct answer. I'm just stating (with my comments and my downvote) that I don't agree that it's *wise* to implicitly endorse his poor solution by helping him scaffold it :-)

Comment: Sure. I uprooted your answer because I think it's probably the best way to go. But it is for the OP to make an informed choice.